# Get first selected cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

When selecting a range in Excel manually, the first cell, or starting cell, of the selection has a different appearance. It does not have a gray layer over it like the rest of the cells in the selection.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

I want to know the following: Is it possible to determine what the starting cell of a selection is using `VBA`?

If this is possible it would go into the `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Selection.Address` will contain the total selected range - from top left to bottom right.

`ActiveCell.Address` will have the cell that was the 'start' of the selection.

You can just refer to these in the event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Selection.Address
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Or `Target.Cells(1, 1).Address`

Comment: I've been racking my brains over this but it never occurred to me to use `ActiveCell` because I try so hard to avoid it. @AlexK. That will always give you the top left cell, or 1st row and 1st column of the target.

Comment: Yes, activecell depends on how the range was selected - it could be the bottom right cell - while cells(1,1) is always top left. It depends what you want